# My problem with form freeze for secend and execute

Tags: c#, events

I tried a lot: `Thread`, `DoWork`, `Async` `Await`, but I got the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'combo' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
```

Here is my code:

```
 public void ggggg()
    {
        var Names = combo.Text;
        string[] strArray = Regex.Split(Names, " - ");
        var port = Convert.ToString(strArray[0]);
        if (port == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Selcet ", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Done", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
    }


     private void BtnNames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
    Thread y = new Thread(delegate () { ggggg(); });
       y.Start();

     }
```

Another part of the code:

```
var Names = this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { combo.Text = combo.Text.Text + ""; }));;
```

Comment: I think My ques not clear what i need how i can run thread without problem when i execute < System.InvalidOperationException>

Comment: Why not do everything needing access to UI controls in `BtnNames_Click` and passing the collected data (in you case `Names`) to the background thread as parameter?

Comment: Could u tell me how???

Comment: Move `var Names = combo.Text;` to `BtnNames_Click` and pass Names as parameter to `ggggg(Names)`.

Comment: I get error No overloaded for method 'ggggg' takes one arguments

Comment: any solution plz

Comment: Then add the parameter: `public void ggggg(string names)`

Comment: Check [How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread) and [Updating Windows Form UI elements from another thread](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/make_it_better/2017/05/15/updating-windows-form-ui-elements-from-another-thread/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add one code before If and work perfect thanks guys

```
public string ggggg(string Names)
{
string[] strArray = Regex.Split(Names, " - ");
return Convert.ToString(strArray[0]);
}
public async void BtnNames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var names = combo.Text;
var port = await Task.Run(() => ggggg(names));
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => // I add this code

if (port == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Selcet ", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but you may try out this:

```
public string ggggg(string Names)
{
    string[] strArray = Regex.Split(Names, " - ");
    return Convert.ToString(strArray[0]);
}


public async void BtnNames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var names = combo.Text;
    var port = await Task.Run(() => ggggg(names));

    if (port == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Selcet ", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: I execute the code but still freezing i don't now why? I don't have any error why freezing...

Comment: Any one know what's my problem